# How to retrieve continuous data from mysql

Tags: ios, mysql, swift

I'm trying to find tutorials or examples on how to load a tableView or collectionView for continuous scrolling.

For example, I have a database of over 1000 entries but I only want to fetch a 100 at a time. Then when the scroll reaches the bottom it automatically loads the next 100, and so on...

Does anyone know of any tutorials or examples?

I'm coding using swift 2 but any objective-C examples would be fine as I can usually figure out the translation.

I have created a test app to try it out. It fetches 20 records starting from zero.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var personTable: UITableView!
var people = []
var startIndex:Int = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.personTable.delegate = self
    self.personTable.dataSource = self
    fetchData()


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.people.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.usernameLabel.text = people[indexPath.row]["username"] as? String
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == people.count - 1{
        self.startIndex += 20
        fetchData()
    }
}

func fetchData(){
    let post = PostService()
    let data = ["startIndex":String(self.startIndex),"limit":"20"]
    let url = "http://**********/index.php?action=fetchPersonList"
    post.post(data, url: url) { (succeeded, msg) -> () in
        if succeeded{
            if msg as! String != "<null>"{
                self.people = msg as! NSArray
                self.personTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

it works when the last cell is reached and reloads the data but doesn't stop until all the rows have been downloaded which is when it throws an error as there is no more data.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

I've looked for the last couple of hours online to try and find examples but either i'm not using the right search terms or there aren't that many out there.

Comment: No MySQL from a web server via PHP.

Comment: @AlMartin If you know the `pagination` concept in php then you will be easily done with the one you are asking for

Comment: Sorry I should have made that clearer. I do understand the pagination concept in PHP but I'm not sure how to set it up in Xcode for the UITableView.

Comment: @AlMartin From xcode, send 2 addintional parameters with request : `noOfRecords`(100 in your case) and `pageNo`(request number : increase a number at each request)

Comment: I've edited my question and put some code to show what I'm trying to achieve. I know how to paginate in MySQL. I don't know how to do it in UITableView.

Comment: @AlMartin try the same code in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method instead of in `willDisplayCell`

Comment: I tried scrollViewDidEndDecelerating but it proved to be unreliable. Some times it doesn't get triggered when scrolling up very slowly. I found scrollViewDidScroll to be much better. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of experimenting with this (that I was hoping to avoid by finding a tutorial which wasn't to be.) I eventually found a method that works.

This is the code that works for me.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var personTable: UITableView!
var people = [NSDictionary]()
var page = 0
var holdPage = false;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.personTable.delegate = self
    self.personTable.dataSource = self
    fetchData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.people.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.usernameLabel.text = people[indexPath.row]["username"] as? String
    return cell
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let actualPosition:CGFloat  = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    let contentHeight:CGFloat  = scrollView.contentSize.height
    let viewHeight:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.height
    if (actualPosition + viewHeight >= contentHeight && self.holdPage == false && self.page < 3) {
        self.holdPage = true //this is used to stop this if statement from running more than once.
        self.page++
        self.fetchData()
    }
}

func fetchData(){
    let post = PostService()
    let startIndex = self.page * 20
    let data = ["startIndex":String(startIndex),"limit":"20"]
    let url = "http://*********/index.php?action=fetchPersonList"
    post.post(data, url: url) { (succeeded, msg) -> () in
        if succeeded{
            if let data = msg as? [NSDictionary]{
                self.people = self.people + data
                self.holdPage = false
                self.personTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I had to use the holdPage variable as I found that when the scroll reached the end it loaded several pages in one go.

The only drawback to this method is that it keeps adding rows to the people array as you scroll down making it bigger each time. I was initially looking to remove the rows that were no longer in view but that was proving to be very complex.

Unless someone can show me a good example?